# Button label changes unexpectedly in React web application on Chrome (latest version) for certain users

Tags: html, reactjs, button, caching, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a front-end web application using React framework, and I'm facing an unusual issue with button labels when the application is accessed by certain users on their phones or PCs using the latest version of Chrome.

The application does **not** utilize any internationalization library, and the button component is implemented purely in HTML with Tailwind CSS. However, some users have reported that the button labels appear to be altered or changed in a strange manner.

I have thoroughly tested the application on multiple devices and browsers, but I haven't been able to reproduce the issue personally. The problem seems to be isolated to specific users and their Chrome browsers.

Can anyone provide insight into why this issue may be occurring? Is there a known **compatibility** issue between** React, Chrome (latest version)**, and Tailwind CSS that could be causing this unexpected behavior? Additionally, are there any alternative **debugging approaches** or potential solutions I could explore to resolve this problem?

I appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this perplexing issue. Thank you!

Here are some pictures of the button having it's label changed from **"Connexion" to "Rapport"** magically..

[app opened from mobile browser user 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImBp7.jpg)

[app opened from web browser user 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqSJk.jpg)

**- I was able to ask a user to use an incognito window and the button label appear normal with the word "Connexion"**

**- I searched my whole code for the word "Rapport" I couldn't find it**

Here is my form and component code:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {(formik) => (
          <Form className="flex flex-col gap-4 items-center w-full">
            <FormikControl
              control="input-mobile"
              label="Numéro de Téléphone"
              type="text"
              name="telephone"
              placeholder="Numéro de Téléphone..."
            />
            <FormikControl
              control="input-mobile"
              label="Mot de passe"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Mot de passe..."
            />
            <i
              onClick={() => navigate("...")}
              className="text-black  text-xs font-semibold self-end">
              Mot de passe oublié ?
            </i>
            <ButtonMobile
              disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
              type="submit"
              label="Connexion"
              filled
            />
            <ButtonMobile
              onClick={() => navigate("...")}
              label="Créer mon compte"
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

```
import React from "react";

function ButtonMobile(props) {
  const { filled, label, onClick, disabled, type, dataBsDismiss } = props;
  if (filled) {
    return (
      <button
        type={type}
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={onClick}
        data-bs-dismiss={dataBsDismiss}
        className="h-12 p-2 w-full rounded-3xl text-white text-sm text-center bg-gradient-to-r from-orangeFrom to-orangeTo shadow-md">
        {label}
      </button>
    );
  }
  if (type === "retour") {
    return (
      <div
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={onClick}
        className="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-full rounded-3xl text-black text-xs text-center border border-orangeFrom shadow-md">
        <span>{label}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <button
      type={type}
      disabled={disabled}
      onClick={onClick}
      className="h-12 w-full rounded-3xl text-black text-xs text-center border border-orangeFrom shadow-md">
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}

export default ButtonMobile;
```